# Creating function from available function

Tags: lua

I'm trying to do script for game which replaces avalible function with created function. So this is my LUA code:

```
function ifEmotePlayed(playerName, emoteID)
if emoteID == 0 then
print(playerName.." is dancing!")
end
end
return 
function eventEmotePlayed(playerName, emoteID)
end
```

Exactly thing i want to do is to replace eventEmotePlayed function with ifEmotePlayed function likely

```
function ifEmotePlayed(playerName, emoteID)
if emoteID==0 then
print(playerName.." is dancing!")
end
end
```

Instead of

```
function eventEmotePlayed(playerName, emoteID)
if emoteID==0 then
print(playerName.." is dancing!")
end
end
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. Can you clarify/paraphrase your question?

Comment: Uh, so I want to replace function eventEmotePlayed with ifEmotePlayed, and I will may use it same as eventEmotePlayed.. uh hard to explain :L

Comment: Something like `local foo = function() print('first') end foo = function() print('second') end`? That replaces foo with the second function definition.

Comment: Simple assignment should do the "replacement": `eventEmotePlayed = ifEmotePlayed`

Comment: I will never understand why everybody thinks it's LUA. Nowhere is it ever formally called LUA :/

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense, `eventEmotePlayed` and `ifEmotePlayed` contain the same exact code. All you're doing is creating another instance of that function object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rename a function you simply do it like that:

```
myNewFunctionName = originalFunctionName
```

Then calling `myNewFunctionName()` will be identical to calling `originalFunctionName()` as `myNewFunctionName` now refers to the same function as `originalFunctionName`.

In Lua functions are variables.

You could also define a function that calls the original function and pass the parameters like:

```
function myNewFunction(a,b)
  return originalFunction(a,b)
end
```

But this is obviously not as efficient as you have to do one additional function call.

If you want to replace a function with your own function so the original function will not be executed but yours instead you simply assign your function to the original functions "name" (actually you make the variable that referred to the original function from now on refer to your own function)

```
function originalFunction(a,b)
  return a + b
end

function myOwnFunction(a,b)
  return a * b
end

originalFunction = myOwnFunction
```

Now `originalFunction` refers to your function and calling `originalFunction(a,b)` will return the product of `a` and `b` instead of the sum. It's the same as in the first example, just the other way around.